# creating NSimage from NSbitmapRep from int* using NSData?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have an int* of rgb data,width, height, and scanlinestride where i would like to create an NSImage.

i have looked around and found that i need to use NSData?

what is the ideal way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this NSBitmapImageRep method:

```
- (id)initWithBitmapDataPlanes:(unsigned char **)planes pixelsWide:(NSInteger)width pixelsHigh:(NSInteger)height bitsPerSample:(NSInteger)bps samplesPerPixel:(NSInteger)spp hasAlpha:(BOOL)alpha isPlanar:(BOOL)isPlanar colorSpaceName:(NSString *)colorSpaceName bitmapFormat:(NSBitmapFormat)bitmapFormat bytesPerRow:(NSInteger)rowBytes bitsPerPixel:(NSInteger)pixelBits
```

Seriously. It’s easy to use though:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
   initWithBitmapDataPlanes:(unsigned char **)&bitmapArray
   pixelsWide:width pixelsHigh:height
   bitsPerSample:8
   samplesPerPixel:3  // or 4 with alpha
   hasAlpha:NO
   isPlanar:NO
   colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
   bitmapFormat:0
   bytesPerRow:0  // 0 == determine automatically
   bitsPerPixel:0];  // 0 == determine automatically

NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(width, height)];

[image addRepresentation:bitmap];
```

Comment: (unsigned char **)&bitmapArray that is an okay cast if bitmapArray is int \*??

Comment: Is it really `int*` data though? You need to use `unsigned char*` to get 8 bits per channel per pixel.

Comment: As far as I know NSBitmapImageRep only accepts chars. If you have ints, you’ll probably need to convert it a char array first. I may be wrong — I’ve only ever worked with image data as chars.

Comment: ah yes, im going to cast it as un unsigned char*.. i think that should work.

Comment: Is the bitmap data copied into the image?  After the addRepresentation, can I free "bitmapArray"?

Comment: No. But you can pass nil for the bitmapArray and initWithBitmapDataPlanes will allocate the necessary amount of memory that you can then copy your bitmapArray data into (via the bitmapData property). Then when the bitmap is released it will free the memory it allocated to hold the pixels.